# Story involving dimensional travel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, telekinesis

A daughter has a vision of her dad being killed and tracks him to a scientific institute. She discovers she has telekinetic abilities and is able to travel to another dimension. It is revealed at the end that the “other dimension” is actually our own through a reference to JFK assassination.

I would have read it in the mid-to-late 1970s, possibly in an anthology. The "institute" was helping people with ESP, telepathy, telekinesis, etc. to develop their abilities. One specific scene I remember is the daughter and another's telekinesis countering each other to keep a die spinning continuously. The institute then used them to investigate a portal (wormhole?) they had opened up. Prior people (including the father) had been driven mad. The daughter survives, enters a dimension where she can smell colors and see sounds. She learns how to enter and leave at will, and is able to use it to instantly travel from one place to another in her world. The two dimensions make a trade agreement for instantaneous transport of goods.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Unfortunately an offhand revenue to the Kennedy assassination as a way of revealing that the main characters are from an alternate universe is rather common.  More details would help

Comment: Please [edit] your question with updates rather than posted them as an "answer".

Comment: The daughter surviving the "other dimension" has some resemblance to *The Universe Between* by Alan E. Nourse, but none of the rest fits that novel other than the date range.

Comment: @LogicDictates that it would have been published after 1963. :D

Comment: Thanks to Zeiss Ikon. I think The Universe Between is the novel I am looking for.